# How to convert exceptions in one namespace to another?

Tags: php

I am working on an API that is handled by the controller api.php

basically, I have models in a different namespace, and I throw exceptions in that namespace.

How do I convert these exceptions into api exceptions?

So in api.php, I catch the exception MyapiException

in the namespace Events, I have my owner Exception class called EventExceptions.

api.php calls models in Events namespace. These models throw EventExceptions. I want to convert these Event Exceptions into MyApiException (like convert the code to MyApiException error codes etc).

Where do I do that? In api.php? or in the EventException class?

Answer (score 2):

You either catch the exact exception or you catch a parent and you throw another one. Let me clarify with an example.

```
namespace \MyApp\API;
class APIException extends \RuntimeException {}

namespace \MyApp\Event;
class EventException extends \RuntimeException {}
```

And now we want to catch an event exception in our API and we only want to catch those.

```
try {
    $concreteEventInstance->fn();
}
catch (\MyApp\Event\EventException $e) {

}
```

No problem so far and you know that part, but now we want to transform this exception into an API exception (for whatever reason), well, we simply throw a new exception with the previous exception.

```
try {
    $concreteEventInstance->fn();
}
catch (\MyApp\Event\EventException $e) {
    throw new \MyApp\API\APIException(
        "My Stackoverflow exception example",
        42,
        $e // <-- See how I attach it as previous exception
    );
}
```

But please note that you can only add the previous exception to the new exception if you have at least PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: How to i convert the error code of the EventException class to an error code of the ApiException class (they have different error codes)? I was thinking of having a static variable that maps the two error codes and a function that maps the EventException error code to an ApiException error code.

Comment: You could define a class that contains the various error codes and of course you have access to the error code when you catch the exception with `$e->getCode()`.